# Android get failed while checking the phpresponse

Tags: php, android

I am trying to store the values in the database in my android. I am able to store the values but my problem is while I am checking to store the values in the database my application is getting crashed at that particular instance I could able to find the error.

Please any one help me in solving this. Here is my short code.

```
 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 


        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Entered data successfully")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(lifequality.this,"Inserted Successully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            myIntent=new Intent(lifequality.this, menu.class);

            String uname;
            uname=myValues.getString("value").toString();

            myIntent.putExtra("value", uname);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }else{
            showAlert(); 
            startActivity(new Intent(lifequality.this, lifequality.class));
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }


}


    public void showAlert(){
        lifequality.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(lifequality.this);
                builder.setTitle("error in inserting.");
                builder.setMessage("not inserted.")  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. In order help the people I am posting here my answer.
Please check your response through debug mode because I am getting the response as "successfully inserted/r /n/n/n". Which I found in debug mode. You also very as it and problem can be solved.